# Angular unit test case failing while using component ngOnInit

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-unit-test

I am using angular 7 and unable to run the unit test case while using `component.ngOnInit()` and `fixture.detectchanges()`. If remove `component.ngOnInit()` and `fixture.detectchanges()` then test case is passing but I want to detect changes after spy.

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppTestingModule, EffectsModule.forRoot([NodeEffects])],
      declarations: [SidenavComponent],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [ApiNodesService]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SidenavComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    browsingService = TestBed.get(BrowsingFilesService);
    apiNodesService = TestBed.get(ApiNodesService);
    appConfig = TestBed.get(AppConfigService);
    // appConfigSpy = spyOn(appConfig, 'get').and.returnValue([navItem]);
  });



  it('check getDocLibraries method is called', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'getDocLibraries');
    fixture.detectChanges();    
    component.ngOnInit();
    component.getDocLibraries();
    fixture.whenStable().then(data => {
      const debugUlElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('ul.sidenav-menu_sub'));
      const nativeUlElement: HTMLUListElement = debugUlElement.nativeElement;
      expect(nativeUlElement.childElementCount).toEqual(1);
    });
  });
  });
```

Error Message:
`TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
            at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
            at SidenavComponent../src/app/components/sidenav/sidenav.component.ts.SidenavComponent.buildMenu (http://localhost:9876/src/app/components/sidenav/sidenav.component.ts?:93:19)
            at SidenavComponent../src/app/components/sidenav/sidenav.component.ts.SidenavComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:9876/src/app/components/sidenav/sidenav.component.ts?:76:28)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/src/app/components/sidenav/sidenav.component.spec.ts?:103:15)`

Comment: try to move "fixture.detectChanges()" just before fixture.whenStable()

Comment: maybe provide the code of your component ?

Comment: i have added my error message also which i am getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your spec in `async` and move detectChanges inside whenStable.

```
  it('check getDocLibraries method is called', async(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'getDocLibraries');
    component.getDocLibraries();
    fixture.whenStable().then(()=> {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      const debugUlElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('ul.sidenav-menu_sub'));
      const nativeUlElement: HTMLUListElement = debugUlElement.nativeElement;
      expect(nativeUlElement.childElementCount).toEqual(1);
    });
    component.ngOnInit();
  }));
```

Note: You have an extra set of '});' at the end?

You could also use fakeAsync & tick instead of async & whenStable

```
  it('check getDocLibraries method is called', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'getDocLibraries');
    component.getDocLibraries();
    component.ngOnInit();
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const debugUlElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('ul.sidenav-menu_sub'));
    const nativeUlElement: HTMLUListElement = debugUlElement.nativeElement;
    expect(nativeUlElement.childElementCount).toEqual(1);
  }));
```